# Flutter adding dynamic row tables in between static rows, with different background color

Tags: flutter, dart, tablerow

I am trying to show a dynamic table,[image]

Following is the code i am using

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: isAPICall
            ? spinner()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: reportList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return reportListData(index);
                }));
  }



 Widget reportListData(int propertyIndex) {
    Data data = reportList[propertyIndex];

    return GestureDetector(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
                child:
                    Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 20.0, 0),
          child: Table(
              border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
              columnWidths: {
                0: FractionColumnWidth(.25),
                0: FractionColumnWidth(.25),
                0: FractionColumnWidth(.25),
                0: FractionColumnWidth(.25),
              },
              children: [
                TableRow(children: [
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: Text(data.level)),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(data.recievedAmt.toString())),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(data.pendingAmt.toString())),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(data.totalAmt.toString())),
                ]),
              ])),
    ]))));
  }
}
```

Here i want to add a header and footer rows.
Header rows is telling the title of each column whereas footer row will be have two columns.

how to add the header and footer in the code
in the same way,

1. if there is no data, need to show text "No Data" with header
   2.i need to add alternative background color for the rows like white and grey -

Answer (score 1):

code sample   :

```
class RadioTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioTestState createState() => _RadioTestState();
}

class _RadioTestState extends State<RadioTest> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  List<String> list;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        print("offset = ${_scrollController.offset}");
      });
    list = List<String>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add(i.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Table(
        children: [
          TableRow(
            children: [
              TableCell(
                child: Text("level"),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 0 "),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 1 "),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 2 "),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if (list.isNotEmpty)
            ...list.map(
              (item) => TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("level-$item"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("-"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("-"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("-"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          TableRow(
            children: [
              TableCell(
                child: Text("footer"),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 0 "),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 1 "),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text("number 2 "),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just did it with some dummy data and put some cases on the data status if its not empty build table row otherwise dont do it .
hope it helped you good luck